# spark window function result value don't reset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was checking out spark window function to check page hit per 30 second,but    it keep on adding value of previous window time too.
suppose at `**12:00:30 count is 10**` and `**12:01:00 count is 10**`.

But spark gives `**output as 20**`
Adding previous window value.I'm using Kafka-spark streaming.

```
 val rs=words.reduceByKeyAndWindow((x,y)=>(x._1 + y._1,x._2 + y._2),Durations.seconds(30))
```

Please help and how i can reset value like window tumbling works in Kafka's KSQL.